# how to add an incremental to a variable name in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there a way to an incremental to a variable name?

```
   for( $i = 1; $i < 10; $i++ ) {
                 $name_$i = 'Prefix: '. $name_$i;
    }
```

Comment: would making an array be a better solution? `$array = new array();`, then `$array[] = 'Prefix: '. $name_$i` and to access the variable `<?=$array[5];?>`?

Comment: You *really* want an array here instead.

Comment: You guys are absolutely right. I have used an array now! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php): `${"name_$i"} = "I'm a variable variable.";`

```
for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
  ${"name_$i"} = $i * $i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried looking for that, but didn't know how to call it! Variable variable makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use variable variables..

Try

```
 ${$name."_".$i} = 'Prefix: '.$name."_".$i;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what arrays are for

```
$name_array = array();
for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
   $name_array[$i] = 'Prefix: '. $name . $i;
}

foreach($name_array AS $key) {
   echo $key; //just to echo out everything in array
}
```

Check out all the different ways PHP can handle arrays ( [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) )

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is YES although I'm not really sure if you need it or not.
Looking at your example you should be able to accomplish this using an array. Using an array is way more memory and cpu friendly.

This example should do the trick:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

```
<?php
$stack = array("orange", "banana");
array_push($stack, "apple", "raspberry");
print_r($stack);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => orange
    [1] => banana
    [2] => apple
    [3] => raspberry
)
```

Now, for you question, [Rob W's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/788192/rob-w) answer should work.